# How to add all elements of one list to each element of another list in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I want to get a list of all the hours for each day of the week, sorted by day and then hour.

I was able to get this list by creating a list of weekdays and a list of hours and then adding the hours to each day of the week by indexing the weekdays list. I know there's a better way to do this. I tried a for loop but it didn't produce the same result. Please show me a better way.

```
weekdays <- c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")
hours <- c("12am","1am","2am","3am","4am", "5am","6am","7am","8am","9am","10am",
           "11am","12pm","1pm","2pm","3pm","4pm","5pm","6pm","7pm","8pm","9pm",
           "10pm","11pm")

monhours <- paste(weekdays[1], hours)
tuehours <- paste(weekdays[2], hours)
wedhours <- paste(weekdays[3], hours)
thuhours <- paste(weekdays[4], hours)
frihours <- paste(weekdays[5], hours)
sathours <- paste(weekdays[6], hours)
sunhours <- paste(weekdays[7], hours)

weekdaysandhours <- c(monhours, tuehours, wedhours, thuhours, frihours, sathours, sunhours)
```

This is the result which is what I want:
"Mon 12am" "Mon 1am"  "Mon 2am"  "Mon 3am"  "Mon 4am"  "Mon 5am"  "Mon 6am"  "Mon 7am"  "Mon 8am"  "Mon 9am"  "Mon 10am" "Mon 11am"
"Mon 12pm" "Mon 1pm"  "Mon 2pm"  "Mon 3pm"  "Mon 4pm"  "Mon 5pm"  "Mon 6pm"  "Mon 7pm"  "Mon 8pm"  "Mon 9pm"  "Mon 10pm" "Mon 11pm"
"Tue 12am" "Tue 1am"  "Tue 2am"  "Tue 3am"  "Tue 4am"  "Tue 5am"  "Tue 6am"  "Tue 7am"  "Tue 8am"  "Tue 9am"  "Tue 10am" "Tue 11am" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `expand.grid` you could do:

```r
dat <- expand.grid(
  hours = hours,
  weekdays = weekdays
)
weekdayshours <- paste(dat$weekdays, dat$hours)

weekdayshours
#>   [1] "Mon 12am" "Mon 1am"  "Mon 2am"  "Mon 3am"  "Mon 4am"  "Mon 5am" 
#>   [7] "Mon 6am"  "Mon 7am"  "Mon 8am"  "Mon 9am"  "Mon 10am" "Mon 11am"
#>  [13] "Mon 12pm" "Mon 1pm"  "Mon 2pm"  "Mon 3pm"  "Mon 4pm"  "Mon 5pm" 
#>  [19] "Mon 6pm"  "Mon 7pm"  "Mon 8pm"  "Mon 9pm"  "Mon 10pm" "Mon 11pm"
#>  [25] "Tue 12am" "Tue 1am"  "Tue 2am"  "Tue 3am"  "Tue 4am"  "Tue 5am" 
#>  [31] "Tue 6am"  "Tue 7am"  "Tue 8am"  "Tue 9am"  "Tue 10am" "Tue 11am"
#>  [37] "Tue 12pm" "Tue 1pm"  "Tue 2pm"  "Tue 3pm"  "Tue 4pm"  "Tue 5pm" 
#>  [43] "Tue 6pm"  "Tue 7pm"  "Tue 8pm"  "Tue 9pm"  "Tue 10pm" "Tue 11pm"
#>  [49] "Wed 12am" "Wed 1am"  "Wed 2am"  "Wed 3am"  "Wed 4am"  "Wed 5am" 
#>  [55] "Wed 6am"  "Wed 7am"  "Wed 8am"  "Wed 9am"  "Wed 10am" "Wed 11am"
#>  [61] "Wed 12pm" "Wed 1pm"  "Wed 2pm"  "Wed 3pm"  "Wed 4pm"  "Wed 5pm" 
#>  [67] "Wed 6pm"  "Wed 7pm"  "Wed 8pm"  "Wed 9pm"  "Wed 10pm" "Wed 11pm"
#>  [73] "Thu 12am" "Thu 1am"  "Thu 2am"  "Thu 3am"  "Thu 4am"  "Thu 5am" 
#>  [79] "Thu 6am"  "Thu 7am"  "Thu 8am"  "Thu 9am"  "Thu 10am" "Thu 11am"
#>  [85] "Thu 12pm" "Thu 1pm"  "Thu 2pm"  "Thu 3pm"  "Thu 4pm"  "Thu 5pm" 
#>  [91] "Thu 6pm"  "Thu 7pm"  "Thu 8pm"  "Thu 9pm"  "Thu 10pm" "Thu 11pm"
#>  [97] "Fri 12am" "Fri 1am"  "Fri 2am"  "Fri 3am"  "Fri 4am"  "Fri 5am" 
#> [103] "Fri 6am"  "Fri 7am"  "Fri 8am"  "Fri 9am"  "Fri 10am" "Fri 11am"
#> [109] "Fri 12pm" "Fri 1pm"  "Fri 2pm"  "Fri 3pm"  "Fri 4pm"  "Fri 5pm" 
#> [115] "Fri 6pm"  "Fri 7pm"  "Fri 8pm"  "Fri 9pm"  "Fri 10pm" "Fri 11pm"
#> [121] "Sat 12am" "Sat 1am"  "Sat 2am"  "Sat 3am"  "Sat 4am"  "Sat 5am" 
#> [127] "Sat 6am"  "Sat 7am"  "Sat 8am"  "Sat 9am"  "Sat 10am" "Sat 11am"
#> [133] "Sat 12pm" "Sat 1pm"  "Sat 2pm"  "Sat 3pm"  "Sat 4pm"  "Sat 5pm" 
#> [139] "Sat 6pm"  "Sat 7pm"  "Sat 8pm"  "Sat 9pm"  "Sat 10pm" "Sat 11pm"
#> [145] "Sun 12am" "Sun 1am"  "Sun 2am"  "Sun 3am"  "Sun 4am"  "Sun 5am" 
#> [151] "Sun 6am"  "Sun 7am"  "Sun 8am"  "Sun 9am"  "Sun 10am" "Sun 11am"
#> [157] "Sun 12pm" "Sun 1pm"  "Sun 2pm"  "Sun 3pm"  "Sun 4pm"  "Sun 5pm" 
#> [163] "Sun 6pm"  "Sun 7pm"  "Sun 8pm"  "Sun 9pm"  "Sun 10pm" "Sun 11pm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `outer` approach.

```
res <- outer(hours, weekdays, Vectorize(\(x, y) paste(y, x))) |> as.vector()

stopifnot(all.equal(weekdaysandhours, res))
```